# How to clear datagridview in c# for displaying another file?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am building an application in which i'm displaying an excel file in `datagridview`. I've given display button for showing data. My problem is once I click button, it works fine but after my second attempt it appends data with previous data. I want to clear datagridview for displaying new data again.
So, what code should I implement?

I tried `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;` and `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();`, but they didn't work for my need

Comment: Been a bit since I used these, but I believe that during initial setup you had to use dataGridView1.DataSource = X, have you attempted to clear the X object?

Comment: setting the data source to null should work so there must be a flaw in your logic elsewhere. Please post more code.

Comment: Setting `DataSource = null` should work.  Sounds like you are appending data to the data source object instead of clearing/overriding the old data.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to clear the datagridview

```vb
dgvImportedExcel.DataSource = Nothing

dgvImportedExcel.Rows.Clear()
```